# iOS 9 iphone 6s Application stuck at didFinishLaunchingWithOptions due to Hockey and Flurry

Tags: ios, ios9, hockeyapp, flurry-analytics

I am using flurry analytics and hockey. I set up those in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

```
[[BITHockeyManager sharedHockeyManager] configureWithIdentifier:@"67905f839393846c26d406894437830e"];
[[BITHockeyManager sharedHockeyManager] startManager];
[[BITHockeyManager sharedHockeyManager].authenticator authenticateInstallation];
[[BITHockeyManager sharedHockeyManager].feedbackManager setFeedbackObservationMode:BITFeedbackObservationModeThreeFingerTap];



// activate flurry
[Flurry setCrashReportingEnabled:YES];
[Flurry startSession:FLURRY_KEY];
[Flurry setUserID:[Helpers getUser]];
```

I don't know why it stuck when it try to register. I am using flurry and hockey in other app too but they are okay. How shall I do?

Answer (score 0):

Just update Flurry SDK. It's fixed in newest version